# Foreach loop with "if" condition on several cores

Tags: r, if-statement, foreach, parallel-processing, domc

How can I use a `if` `else` condition in a `foreach` loop and use multiple cores?
I would like to do something like:

```
library(parallel)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(detectCores()-1) 

# detectCores()-1
# [1] 7

source("my_file.R")
source("my_function.R")

A<- foreach(i=1:10) %dopar%
{
    if (i<5) my.file <- my_file(i)
    else     my.file <- my_file(i*i)

    my_function(my.file)
}
```

It works, but when I open a `top` on my terminal, I see that it runs on just one core and my objective is to parallelize on several cores.

Comment: Using an "if" inside a foreach loop should not prevent the use of multiple cores. The primary cause of this problem is building R with OpenBLAS or GOTOBLAS 2. Has your R installation been built with one of these?

Comment: I don't know. R was already installed on my computer. I work with it.